# Vertex Attrib Divisor not Working for Instanced Rendering

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, instance

I have this bit of code that sets up my vertex attribute pointers for rendering:

```
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, renderer->instancesBuffer);
  enableFloatVertexAttribute(attributePosition, 2, sizeof(struct surfaceInstance), 0, 1);
  enableFloatVertexAttribute(attributeSize, 2, sizeof(struct surfaceInstance), (void*) (2 * sizeof(float)), 1);
  enableFloatVertexAttribute(attributeAngle, 1, sizeof(struct surfaceInstance), (void*) (4 * sizeof(float)), 1);
  enableFloatVertexAttribute(attributeIdentifier, 1, sizeof(struct surfaceInstance), (void*) (5 * sizeof(float)), 1);
  enableFloatVertexAttribute(attributeAtlasOffset, 2, sizeof(struct surfaceInstance), (void*) (6 * sizeof(float)), 1);
  enableFloatVertexAttribute(attributeTextureSize, 2, sizeof(struct surfaceInstance), (void*) (8 * sizeof(float)), 1);
...
void enableFloatVertexAttribute(int32_t attribute, uint32_t size, uint32_t stride, void const *offset, uint32_t divisor) {
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(attribute);
  glVertexAttribPointer(attribute, size, GL_FLOAT, stride, GL_FALSE, offset);
  if(divisor != 0) glVertexAttribDivisor(attribute, divisor);
}
...
layout(location = 0) in vec2 vertex;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 position;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 size;
layout(location = 3) in float angle;
layout(location = 4) in float identifierPass;
layout(location = 5) in vec2 atlasOffset;
layout(location = 6) in vec2 textureSize;
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

It sets up the attributes of the buffer below:

[image]

Which is created by calling:

```
surfaceRendererAppendSurface(renderer, 100, 100, 48, 48, glfwTime, 1);
surfaceRendererAppendSurface(renderer, 200, 100, 48, 48, glfwTime, 1);
```

As one can see, the data is sent to the GPU properly, the first instance is drawn properly and the GPU is drawing the adequate number of instances, but when I profile my application, the second, third, or fourth instance is all wrong, not following the buffer supplied at all... Which leads me to believe it is a problem with division what is even more bizarre, is that when i switch my divisor to 2, the second instance is drawn well, and then 3, and the third is drawn correctly... It is very weird and I have no idea what is going on...

Case in point: Instance 1 = perfectly copied!
[image]

Instance = What the hell happened???
[image]

(Looking at it right now... it looks like vertexAttribDivisor had no effect!)

Comment: What is the difference between a "vertex" and a "position"?

Comment: @NicolBolas the vertex attribute is another buffer ... the buffer i've shown if position and up only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (Looking at it right now... it looks like vertexAttribDivisor had no effect!)

To me, it looks like your `stride` is completely off. And voila, you swapped the function parameters:

> ```
> glVertexAttribPointer(attribute, size, GL_FLOAT, stride, GL_FALSE, offset);
>                                                          ^^^^^^^^ this is actually what you set as stride
> ```

Since `GL_FALSE` is 0, and the GL intepretes a stride of 0 as tightly packed array, the data in the screenshot makes perfect sense.